# CodeIgniter: Sessions aren't being cleared from 'ci_sessions` table

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm having a little issue with my CodeIgniter setup.
I configured CodeIgniter to save & store the sessions in the `ci_session` table in the Database. As I've read a little about it, I understand that every time the session library loads it should clean the table in the DB for old sessions.
Today I accessed my DB and I saw that the table is already containing `600 sessions`, when It's only me & friend developing the system and there are no other users that accessing the pages, and after sorting in the DB the `timestamp` column I saw that it stored records from the `5th of October`.

I want it to clear the old sessions of course.

Here's my configuration of the session from `config.php` file:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400;     // Default: 7200
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Please advise.

Thanks,
Slavik.

Answer (score 1):

Until the garbage collection kicks in, the expired sessions are not deleted. It is called randomly, and the frequency is based on the [`session.gc_divisor`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor) and [session.`gc_probability`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) parameters.

If you want to happen as soon as possible, you should decrease `session.gc_divisor`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So just let me understand it... it calculates the action by a probability... so for example in my case, `session.gc_probability = 1`, and `session.gc_divisor = 1000`, so is that makes it that 1 session/user is accessing out of 1000 the website, will trigger the cleaning event? 
If so, I'll surely reduce the `gc_divisor` value, to `100` or something like that.

Comment: Yes, you have 0.1% probability to call the gc. With `gc_divisor` to `100`, it's increases to 1%

Comment: To Ad to the above answer, the database field `user_agent` may not be large enough to hold the complete string for the user agent(hence new sessions are generated) try change its type to TEXT instead of Varchar

Comment: @Philip, hi, actually I'm not storing `user_agent` in any field, I tried adding the field but it does not store anything in it. Maybe it's additional configuration, but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: ci_sessions table stores the user agent like so `user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL` as far as I remember, at least for version 2.X. This would cause the issue I suggested.